# Filter array by deleting adjacent objects with duplicate property value

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to figure out how to filter my array by removing adjacent objects that have the same value of a specified property.

I want to remove adjacent objects with the same `item`, as the same one would come back eventually later on and I'd still want to have those recorded.

So this array for example...

```
[
    {
        item: "Car",
        tstamp: 1609605221607
    },
    {
        item: "Car",
        tstamp: 1609605226605
    },
    {
        item: "Truck",
        tstamp: 1609605231610
    },
    {
        item: "Car",
        tstamp: 1609605236604
    }
]
```

Would filter to this...

```
[
    {
        item: "Car",
        tstamp: 1609605221607
    },
    {
        item: "Truck",
        tstamp: 1609605231610
    },
    {
        item: "Car",
        tstamp: 1609605236604
    }
]
```

Removes `car`'s object recorded at 1609605226605

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You just need a variable to maintain track of what the last item was. Then, you can use the `filter` method to remove any items that are equal to the `lastItem`.

```js
const items = [
    {
        item: "Car",
        tstamp: 1609605221607
    },
    {
        item: "Car",
        tstamp: 1609605226605
    },
    {
        item: "Truck",
        tstamp: 1609605231610
    },
    {
        item: "Car",
        tstamp: 1609605236604
    }
];

let lastItem;

const filtered = items.filter(el => {
  if (el.item === lastItem) {
    return false;
  }
  lastItem = el.item;
  return true;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Another way to do this would be to use `reduce` and just compare the current element item to the accumulator's last element. Only add it if they're different.

```js
const items = [
    {
        item: "Car",
        tstamp: 1609605221607
    },
    {
        item: "Car",
        tstamp: 1609605226605
    },
    {
        item: "Truck",
        tstamp: 1609605231610
    },
    {
        item: "Car",
        tstamp: 1609605236604
    }
];

const filtered = items.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const lastItem = acc[acc.length - 1]?.item;
  if (lastItem !== el.item) acc.push(el);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filtered);
```